# to find primitive roots of a galois field

Tags: galois-theory

I need to find the members of Galois Field with $p = 11$.
I proceeded in this way:
$x^{10} - 1 = 0 $

implies $\frac{(x^{10}-1)}{(x+1)(x^{5}-1)} = 0  $
which implies $x^{4} - x^{3} + x^{2} - x + 1 =0$

Now I am stuck as I am not being able to reduce this polynomial.How to find it's roots?

Comment: You need to begin with $\mathbb F_{11} = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, 10\}$ and figure out which of the ten nonzero elements are _not_ roots of either $x^2-1$ or $x^5 - 1$ (or both). These _non-roots_ of $x^2-1$ and $x^5-1$ are the primitive elements you are looking for, and you could, if you want to, make assurance doubly sure by verifying that they _are_ roots of $x^{10}-1$.

Comment: Spelling nitpick: It's "Galois" with no apostrophe -- the "s" is part of the name, not a possessive. (It's also silent, but that's just French).

Comment: The thing is I have to solve the equation in the traditional way and obtain the roots according to my professor.

Comment: @kris91: $x^{10}=1$ then $x_i=cis(\frac {i2\pi}{n})$ for $i=0,1,2...9$ can't you use this?